# How to make Cafe Gram bouncy pancakes? (Fluffiest pancakes in the world)

Tags: pancakes

I have read [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3078/how-to-make-thick-and-fluffy-pancakes) on making thick and fluffy pancakes but I think that the Japanese Cafe Gram goes beyond the normal "fluffy pancake". [See video of the pancake here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i7HoV5z54j8)

[image: Cafe Gram Pancakes]

*Cafe Gram Pancakes*

Are there any additional steps or substitutions that this cafe has taken to create these insanely fluffy and bouncy pancakes that have been dubbed the fluffiest pancakes in the world?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than simply poured onto a griddle, Japanese pancakes are molded using a paper collar, almost like a soufflé.

The batter needs to be very tender to keep it from becoming tough. The easiest way to do this is to make a well in the dry ingredients, then add the liquid.

Buttermilk is key to the flavor of pancakes - lemon juice or vinegar doesn't taste right.

To blend the egg and oil with minimum stirring, one recipe I saw called for a small (1 Tbsp) of Japanese style mayo, which they claimed helped emulsify the ingredients, leading to a smooth texture with less stirring. Kewpie brand is the most popular, and has a distinct taste from American Mayo that helps it blend into a pancake more easily.